# Handling 'Error in exception handler' error in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I get the "Error in exception handler" error very often, mainly because of file permission issue, and sometimes because of error in code.

I want to redirect user to a custom error page every time the system encounters the 'error in exception handler' error.

How do I handle this error?

Answer (score 4):

It's because Laravel can't write to the logfile. If you don't want logs, you can disable it in `app/start/global.php` around line 55:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error(...); //comment out this line.
});
```

But honestly, that would be a symptom-treatment instead of a problem-treatment. You should `chown` the `app/storage` recursively to the user running the server. Fastest way:

1. In `public/index.php`, at the very top, temporarily put in `` die(`whoami`) `` just after the opening `<?php`-tag.
2. Load any page and copy whatever it prints on the site. Let's say it's `www-data`.
3. Fire up a terminal/console, go to your project root and run `chown www-data -R app/storage`, swapping `www-data` with whatever you found in step two.